# JComboBox popup menu constant height

Tags: java

I have a JComboBox with a key listener on the editor textbox that serves to make it filterable.  The filtering works fine, but I'm having a problem getting the corresponding popup box to always remain at a set height - and this problem only comes up after a value has been explicitly set either by clicking on an item in the popup or hitting enter while an entry is hilighted.

For example, say my combobox had the values [BOOP, KOOP, JOOP, MOOP, FOOP, DOOP, ROOP, ZOOPS] and I typed in 'OOPS'.  At that point, only the value 'ZOOPS' would display in the popup, but its size would still be large enough to accomodate all of the other values without needing to scroll.

However, once I explicitly select 'ZOOPS', if I then click back on the editor textbox and delete the 'S' so that only 'OOP' remains, all of the entries are added back in correctly, but the size of the popup is now only large enough to show a single item with tiny scrollbars on the side for navigating to the other entries.  Oddly enough, if I hit the escape key at this point, the popup corrects itself and shows all the items once again.

I've tried setting the height of the popup box manually with:

```
Dimension size = new Dimension(comboBox.getWidth(), 146);
JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) comboBox.getUI().getAccessibleChild(comboBox, 0);
popupMenu.setPopupSize(size);
```

However, that only seems to set the size of whatever bounding component the actual popup menu is contained in - it results in a transparent box of the size that I want but the actual popup menu is still only large enough for a single item.

I tried setSize(), setMinimumSize(), setMaximumSize() - all to no avail.  Any clues as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: Best if you could create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As an aside, it is almost always better to avoid use of KeyListeners in this situation. Better to filter the document or listen to the document.

Comment: Setting the size of the popup is an absolute pain in the ... pants